# Pandas group by date range of one column and apply values to list of a second column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-resample

I have set my index to be dates.
I can group the dates per month and apply an aggregating function, but I cannot group the dates by month and apply(list) the values of another column (the column named "Stuff"):

```
df.resample('M')['Stuff'].apply(list)
```

This brings up an error message:

```
ValueError: Length of passed values is 64, index implies 65.
```

Comment: `df['Stuff'].resample('M').apply(list)`?

Comment: It worked, thank you Quang, you an post it as the answer!